# i have install face_recognition_models but it is not importing in vscode and keep saying inytsall face_recognition model consider i am a new mac user

Tags: python, macos, face-recognition, dlib

please install `face_recognition_models` with this command before using `face_recognition`:

terminal command;

apple@macbook-pro-18 ~ % pip3 install face_recognition_models
Requirement already satisfied: face_recognition_models in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (0.3.0)
apple@macbook-pro-18 ~ %

Answer (score 0):

Normally installation of `face_recognition` includes automatic installation of all prerequisites (like `dlib`) and `face_recognition_models` as well. My advice is to uninstall everything you've installed and then

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install face-recognition
```

Finally, you should run your Py script under the same user you've installed the modules I guess.